# Webform bespoke results

Tags: webforms

I am hoping for some pointers from the community if possible please. We recently rebuilt our website in Drupal 8. Previously it was made in the the old-fashioned way with Dreamweaver. It was quite old!

Now, on the old website we had a fun little tool made with some custom php code. The user answered some questions. In the background, weightings were applied to different attributes based on the answers and the result was some page recommendations for the user displayed on-screen.

The topic of the website is scuba diving and marine life, and in our case this recommended scuba diving destinations. It is not commercial, just a bit of fun. A simplified example would be:

Q1: How many dives do you have?
a) Under 25
b) Under 50
c) More than 50

Q2: What type of diving do you like?
a) Coral reefs
b) Ship wrecks
c) Underwater photography

etc..

We then have a list of dive destinations, which would gain a score based on the answers.

So, if Destination 1 was good for beginners and coral reefs, and the user answered a) to Q1 and Q2, Destination 1 might get a score of 3 for each answer, and a total score of 6. Destination 2 might be good for experienced divers who like underwater photography, so would score well if someone answered c) to both questions.

Of course, there are some more questions and more possible destinations. The end result was a list of 6 destinations (the top scoring ones) that we thought they should check out, with links to those pages on the website.

I'd love to recreate it on the new website in Drupal 8. I have been looking at the Webform module. Certainly I could use this to ask questions and collate results. I am not so confident if it (or any module) could be used to process the answers and create the recommendations?

I am ok with coding, but not at the level of creating my own module in Drupal, nor do I really have the time for that at present.

Can I seek some expert opinions please on if Webform or another module could help me achieve this, or if it is a little too bespoke.

Thank you in advance. I am of course happy to provide some more context if I have missed out anything crucial.

Phil

Comment: Hi Pill you can use h5p module is a great module for questions and answers and have interesting options of configuration

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.